# Numbers of the form $8k^2-1$ in a sequence defined by $a_0=-1$, $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, pell-type-equations

> Suppose a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is defined by $a_0=-1$, $a_1=1$ and $$a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Find all $n$ such that $a_n$ is of the form $8k^2-1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

The problem comes from [Bulgaria National Olympiad 2003, Problem 3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h590645p3498216):

> Given the sequence $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}_+}$ defined by $y_1=y_2=1$ and
>   $$y_{n+2}=(4k-5)y_{n+1}-y_n+4-2k,\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}_+.$$
>   Find all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $y_n$ is a perfect square for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$.

I attempted to solve this problem by using the fact that $y_2=2k-2$ and $y_3=8k^2-20k+3$ are perfect squares. Let $2k-2=(2u)^2$ and $8k^2-20k+3=v^2$, and we have negative Pell's equation $$(8u^2-1)^2-2v^2=-1.$$ The general solution to $x^2-2y^2=-1$ is given by $x_n+y_n\sqrt{2}=(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}$, thus leading to my original question.

Obviously, $a_0=-1$ and $a_2=7$ is of the form $8k^2-1$. How do I prove that these are the only solutions?

Comment: It seems that there are many ... but I do not know how to prove anything in number theory.

Answer (score 0):

Work in progress ...

**Proposition 1.** $a_{2k} \equiv -1 \pmod{8}$

**Proof.** Leaving the [theoretical material aside](http://nms.lu.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/21-linear-recurrences.pdf), characteristic polynomial of the recurrent sequence is
$$x^2-6x+1=0$$
with the solutions $x_1=3-2\sqrt{2},x_2=3+2\sqrt{2}$, thus
$$a_n=A(3-2\sqrt{2})^n+B(3+2\sqrt{2})^n$$
or, [given the initial conditions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A%2BB%3D-1,A(3-2%5Csqrt%7B2%7D)%2BB(3%2B2%5Csqrt%7B2%7D)%3D1)
$$a_n=\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)(3-2\sqrt{2})^n+\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)(3+2\sqrt{2})^n$$
[One thing to mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) is that
$$(3-2\sqrt{2})^n=C-D\sqrt{2}\\
(3+2\sqrt{2})^n=C+D\sqrt{2}$$
both $C,D \in \mathbb{Z}$ [and](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D)(C-D%5Csqrt%7B2%7D)%2B(-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D)(C%2BD%5Csqrt%7B2%7D))
$$a_n=2D-C$$
But
$$C=3^{n}+\binom{n}{2}3^{n-2}(2\sqrt{2})^2+\binom{n}{4}3^{n-4}(2\sqrt{2})^4+...=3^{n}+8Q$$
$$D=\binom{n}{1}3^{n-1}2+\binom{n}{3}3^{n-3}2^3\sqrt{2}^2+\binom{n}{5}3^{n-5}2^5\sqrt{2}^4+...=n3^{n-1}2+8R$$
Thus 
$$a_n+1=2D-C+1=n3^{n-1}4-3^{n}+1+16R-8Q$$
Or if
$$3^{n-1}(4n-3)+1\equiv 0 \pmod{8} \Rightarrow a_n \equiv -1 \pmod{8}$$
which is true only for even $n=2k$, since
$$4n-3=8k-3 \equiv -3 \pmod{8}\Rightarrow 3^{n-1}(4n-3)+1 \equiv -3^{2k}+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{8} \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**Note** for odd $n=2k+1 \Rightarrow 4n-3=8k+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{8} \Rightarrow$ $3^{n-1}(4n-3)+1 \equiv 3^{2k}+1 \not\equiv  0 \pmod{8}$, since $9 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: I thought of that too. This kind of linearly recursively defined sequences becomes periodic modulo any integer. But there are $a_0$ and $a_2$ that work, so simply modulo $8$ doesn't work...